# How can I set text in another TextView in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I created a `RecyclerView` adapter. And when I add a new item I need to set the text in two `TextView`. In the first `TextView(android:id="@+id/text")` I can set text without any problem. How could I set text in `TextView(android:id="@+id/textCost")` by methot:

```
private double SumCost(String result){
        switch (result){
            case "4820049490145":
                return 2.34;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Imr7h.png)
Because `String result` I get from `ScanPage`.Thanks for any help.

My full code:
`activity_scan_page.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SumText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="0.00"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scanBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Scan now"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:contentPadding="5dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textCost"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
            android:text="Delete" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

ScanPage.java (I get `IntentResult result` here, and set `android:id="@+id/text"` by `items.add(result)`;):

```
package com.example.scanapp;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class ScanPage extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


    Button scanBtn;
    TextView editText;

    List<String> items = new LinkedList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_page);



        scanBtn = findViewById(R.id.scanBtn);
        scanBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

    }
    public void AddItem(String result){          
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        DemoAdapter adapter = new DemoAdapter(items);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        items.add(result);

    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        scanCode();
    }

    private  void scanCode(){
        IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        integrator.setCaptureActivity(CaptureAct.class);
        integrator.setOrientationLocked(false);
        integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
        integrator.setPrompt("Scanning code");
        integrator.initiateScan();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(result != null){
            if(result.getContents() != null){
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setMessage(result.getContents());
                builder.setTitle("Scanning Result");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();

                        ///
                        AddItem(result.getContents());
                        ///

                        editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.SumText);
                        editText.setText(Cost(SumCost(result.getContents())));
                    }
                });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this,"No result", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
    ////////

    double SumVar = 0;


    private double SumCost(String result){
        switch (result){
            case "4820049490145":
                return 2.34;
            default: return 0;
        }
    }
    private String Cost(double cost){
        SumVar += cost;
        return Double.toString(SumVar);
    }
    ////////
}
```

DemoAdapter.java:

```
package com.example.scanapp;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.List;

public class DemoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DemoVH>{

    List<String> items;

   

    public DemoAdapter(List<String> items){
        this.items = items;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DemoVH onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
        return new DemoVH(view).linkAdapter(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DemoVH holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(items.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}

class DemoVH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView textView;

    private DemoAdapter adapter;

    public DemoVH(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete).setOnClickListener(view -> {
            adapter.items.remove(getAdapterPosition());
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
        });
    }
    public DemoVH linkAdapter(DemoAdapter adapter){
        this.adapter = adapter;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass result value with static reference.

Comment: use modelclass in your recyclerview

Comment: In `ScanPage` I tried to create a `public double CostItem;` and then assign a value to it in the `AddItem` method(`double CostItem = SumCost(result);`), but the result was 0.0. I added the code `holder.textViewSum.setText(Double.toString(scanPage.CostItem));` to the "onBindViewHolder" method and `TextView textView;` ,  `textViewSum = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textCost);`

Comment: @Ribter I don't understand exactly what you want to say. Please add more information to your question.

Comment: I need to set TextView(`android:id="@+id/textCost`) when creating an item. Now I am trying to solve this by model class.

Answer (score 0):

You must call notifyItemInserted() in your AddItem() method:

```
...
items.add(result);
notifyItemInserted(position)
}
```